# How do I capture human relationships in a Railsy way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `FamilyTree` that users will be added to where they can invite other members of their family.

What I am trying to do is create a smart relationship, where if I invite my son, once I specify he is my son, then the system should automagically know that I am his father.

I figure the only way to do this is to enforce genders on all user records, which is fine.

I also have the following models:

- FamilyTree
- Membership
- User

Each user has_one family_tree. Each FamilyTree has_many memberships.

So whenever a user joins a family_tree, a membership is created for them on that FamilyTree.

What I am trying to figure out though is, how do I handle the two-sided relations. 
i.e. `User A` adds `User B`. I was thinking of creating a new model called `Relationships` that would perhaps look like this:

- ID
- user_one_id
- user_two_id
- relation

But the issue with this, is that each record doesn't tell you exactly what's what. i.e. it doesn't tell you how that `user1` is the father of `user2`, etc. So it would be dependent on the code to know that the relation is always going from the direction of `user_1 -> user_2`.

How do I avoid this problem altogether or figure out an alternative way to represent/think about this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you mapping only parent <-> child relationships? Or do you have other things like siblings, uncles/aunts, etc.?

Comment: @smathy I want to be able to map all of those - i.e. if I am a male, and I invite a relative that is a male and I add the relation of him being my brother, the system should automatically add me as his brother. The same would apply to uncles/aunts/nieces/nephews/grandfathers/etc. Hope that answers your question.

Comment: My question was a little ambiguous and therefore I still didn't get the information I was after :) What I mean is in the DB are you going to record all those other types of relationships? Because, you could represent everything as just parent <-> child, eg. if Marc enters Jason as a brother then your logic could just add Jason to the children of Marc's parents (perhaps after confirming they're the same parents). I think that's the best way to go and simplifies the DB so that actually you could just have a User with `father_id` and `mother_id`

Comment: @smathy But then I guess the issue with that is that in order to assign a relation it will always be relative to either `parent` or `child`? In other words, say I want to enter John, who is Marc's cousin. I would first have to enter John's parents and then make sure they are brothers/sisters of Marc's parents, before saying that John is Jack's son? That seems cumbersome. Or did you have something else in mind? With that structure, how would I capture Marc's niece/nephew/cousin (assuming that none of their parents/children are already entered). i.e. this is the first time they are entering tree

Comment: No, that's what I had in mind. You would then create placeholder entries for those relatives, this is common in a family tree where you display the whole tree with the missing places shown as well, then the user can see everything laid out. The alternative is what I think would be cumbersome and honestly I can't imagine how you would work out all the different relationships. There are many different ways that two cousins could be connected, knowing only that they're cousins won't help you display the family tree as s whole.

Comment: That sounds VERY complicated - almost waaaaay too complicated. Any other ideas?

Comment: simple join table where you have one user model represented under both parent_id and child_id?

Comment: @mymlyn Can you show an example with some code please? Thanks.

Comment: i had like 4 ideas last 5 minutes, and atm i think that smathy's solutuion might actually be the easiest one you could use

Comment: I still am unsure re: how that may work for things like cousins/nephews/etc. I would love to see some code.

Comment: He is right. The easiest way is having a user model and a relationship model representing parent-child relationships. As for the cousins, etc. you would have to insert placeholder objects to save them and use helper methods that define the different relationships to retrieve the cousins, aunts, etc. This part could get complicated, but at least your datamodel would be very lean and very flexible in regard to the relationships you can model on top of it using the helpers.

Comment: btw: I am trying to formualte an answer with some code examples right now, but as you can surely imagine it is getting more and more complicated ;)

Comment: https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry and http://railscasts.com/episodes/262-trees-with-ancestry?view=comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As users can have multiple parents and multiple children, the easiest database model would be having two models, a user model and a relationship model which should look something like this:

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :child, class_name: 'User'

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :parent_child_relationships, class_name: "Relationship", foreign_key: :child_id
  has_many :parents, through: :parent_child_relationships, source: :parent

  has_many :child_parent_relationships, class_name: "Relationship", foreign_key: :parent_id      
  has_many :children, through: :child_parent_relationships, source: :child

end
```

Using helper methods you could now retrieve theoretically all other types of relationships, for example cousins could be something like this:

```
def cousins
  parent_generation = parents.map(&:parents).flatten.map(&:children).flatten
  return (parent_generation - parents).map(&:children).flatten
end
```

When it comes to adding new relatives other than parents or children, it gets really complicated. Here I would recommend to only allow users to add parents, children and maybe siblings and let the build more complex family trees only using these 3 'operators'. A method to add a sibling could look like this:

```
def add_sibling(user_params)
  sibling = User.new user_params
  sibling.parents = parents
  sibling.save
end
```

Granted, it is pretty complicated (and it doesn't get easier with validations, existing and new users or fancier relationships). But what you are trying to do is pretty complicated and I still think, this would be easiest and most flexible way to go.

**Edit 1: More detail on how to model more complex relationships**

I don't think, there is a good way to capture the more complex relationships in rails associations (if there is any), because as soon as you start using extra conditions for `has_many` you already have to use `user.siblings.build` or `user.siblings.create` to help Rails making sure they are met automatically.  In our case however, that the conditions we would need for a sibling relationship are not only based on attributes, but also on other objects in the database (that would need to be created to meet the conditions). This makes me think, that it might even be impossible.

However, there might not be a way to let Rails do the heavy lifting here, but you could definitely define setter methods on the user class such as the `def add_sibling(user_params)` methods or even recreate the Rails API buy creating something like a `CousinAssociation` class for every relationship (possibly inheriting from a common `FamilyAssociation` class to keep it DRY) that overwrites the `<<` operator, the `.add` method and all that stuff and would be returned by  `user.cousins` to allow `user.cousins << new_cousin` etc. It would be like the original `ActiveRecord::Association` tailored to your needs.

Regardless of the option you choose above, when it comes to adding cousins or siblings where the common parents are not in the database yet, the (over-)written setter methods of both approaches will have to check if someone in the relationship chain is missing. In that case they should just create a 'John Doe' user to link the relatives, that could be edited by the application user afterwards to match the real names, etc (if known).

Comment: Yeh I am liking this approach. I do wonder if I would be better off using something like awesome nested set - to represent the tree and then use those helper methods to help me traverse the tree - as opposed to having it all manually done from scratch now.

Comment: You could be better off. I do not have experience with any of the mentioned gems, so I can't give you a definitive answer. It can save you a lot of work, but for example I am not sure how well they support graphs with multiple parents and children. Also, you will have to think about how much you will have to customize (ie for validations) and how easy those gems are customizable or in what way they maybe already offer the needed functionalities. In the end, the code above should give you a good starting point, but it is always worth to check out some gems before starting serious coding.

Comment: @marcamillion: Is there still something you miss to completely answer your question? I was just wondering as you seemed to like the approach but still did not mark the thread as answered.

Comment: I am implementing it, to make sure it covers everything I need. I will accept and apply bounty before it expires.

Comment: Here is a question for you, I like the way you broke out the `parent` and `child` relationships. Ideally, I would love to do the same for all the others, i.e. sibling, cousin, etc. That way, i can just do `user.siblings` or `user.cousins` or even `user.cousins << new_cousin`. Given the `Relationship` model you setup here, what's the best way to approach this? I know that you did it via a method for each relationship. But I can't quite reconcile what happens on that first `cousin` record, when they don't have any parents or children in the db already. How do we tackle that?

Comment: I added more details on the way I would approach the complex relationships to my answer. However, if I would code the app, I would still restrict it to adding only parents, children and maybe siblings as not only the backend code, but also the UI and everything around it will get more complicated with every link farther away from 'simple' parent-child relationships :)